# LoadLibrary() - "Invalid Access Memory Location (998)"

Tags: dll, loadlibrary

Let me start off by saying I had one DLL loading in just fine. But when I go to load a second DLL it always errors out with a "Invalid Access Memory Location (998)" error.

In my project the DLLs basically contain the code needed to run an AI. Another application I built allows you to write simple code and then behind the scenes it compiles the source and makes it available to the "game".

Basically I'm able to load one AI (DLL) in and watch it do its thing. The next time I send it a command to load a new AI (Separately and for a different entity) it fails. I'm using new variables for the whole process so it shouldn't be stepping on other modules.

Each DLL looks pretty much the same since they are all built in basically the same way. (the DLL just consists of a bunch of structs and one function). I was thinking that perhaps there is something in common in the DLLs that make it share part of the same memory in someway but I have no idea.

I wish I could show you the DLL source, but it's not on this machine.

If you have any ideas, thanks in advance!

-Michael

Edit: The proper name of the 998 error is "ERROR_NOACCESS". Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's very late… but maybe this can help:

[How to Configure Memory Protection in Windows XP SP2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700810.aspx) (Published: December 9, 2004)

The page mentioned provides the following information:

- Introduction
- Before You Begin
- Enabling DEP for all Programs on Your Computer
- Enabling the DEP Exception List
- Configuring System-wide DEP Options
- Related Information